# Multiplication assistant multiplicand sequence error VBA

Tags: excel, vba, math

I am building a multiplication assistant that (on purpose) only does half the working out for calculating the answer of multiplication of any two 1 digit numbers.

I believe it will be a useful aid in helping students of all ages learn mental multiplication. It is hoped that a program like this can help individuals connect the dots as to why multiplied numbers are the way they are without resorting to the difficulty of memorizing large multiplication tables (this one is 4x4 = 16 not 10x10 = 100)

I believe we live in an unhealthy world of technological reliance, this simple program should help people use their own calculator - the one in their head.

You simply add up the numbers that are not greyed out, for example 6 x 8 = *mental calculation* 16+32= 48

Problem description:-
The program doesn't calculate correctly if the multiplier is selected before the multiplicand, for example 3 (multiplicand) x5 (multiplier) = gives 1+2+4+8 =*mental math* 15 which is correct
If done in reverse multiplier 5 x multiplicand 3 result is 1+2+4+8+2+4+8+16 = 45 which is incorrect

Thank you in advance,
Kevin

screenshot of multiplication assistant
[image]

across is the multiplicands and columns are the multipliers, code is visual basic for excel (VBA)

```
Private Sub across1_Click()
Range("A2:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A1:D1").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across2_Click()
Range("A1:D1").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A3:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A2:D2").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across3_Click()
Range("A3:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A1:D2").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across4_Click()
Range("A1:D2").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A4:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A3:D3").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across5_Click()
Range("A2:D2").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A4:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A1:D1").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Range("A3:D3").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across6_Click()
Range("A1:D1").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A4:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A2:D3").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across7_Click()
Range("A4:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A1:D3").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across8_Click()
Range("A1:D3").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A4:D4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub across9_Click()
Range("A2:D3").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("A1:D1").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Range("A4:D4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub


Private Sub columns1_Click()
Range("B1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns2_Click()
Range("A1:A4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("C1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns3_Click()
Range("C1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns4_Click()
Range("A1:B4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("D1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns5_Click()
Range("B1:B4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("D1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns6_Click()
Range("A1:A4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
Range("D1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns7_Click()
Range("D1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns8_Click()
Range("A1:C4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub columns9_Click()
Range("B1:C4").Font.Color = RGB(202, 204, 206)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A1:D4").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub Frame2_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
```